# iOS: How can I refresh MKMapView user location everytime the user loads the app

Tags: ios, iphone, mkmapview, xcode5

I'm implement MKMapView and works fine when the user loads the app for the very first time but after that it doesn't refresh the user locations even when the user comes back from background.

This part of my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.mapView.delegate=self;
    self.mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.userTrackingMode = MKUserTrackingModeFollow;
    self.mapView.zoomEnabled = YES;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
```

I tried implement the code above in viewWillAppear to see if it will reload every time the user loads the app but it didn't work.

any of you knows of has any idea of how can reload the mapview everytime the app loads?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below delegate method for this:

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a little unclear what you mean by "doesn't refresh user location" and "reload" so I'm assuming what you want is to re-center the map on the user's current location on reload.

First, to trigger things, you'll need code in the AppDelegate applicationDidBecomeActive: or applicationWillEnterForeground: method. That's your "trigger" notification where you can initiate action.

Then, to recenter on current location, something like:

```
- (void) _putMapToCurrentlLocation
{
    CLLocation* location = [[LocationManager sharedInstance] currentLocation];

    MKCoordinateRegion newRegion;
    newRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.13;
    newRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.12;
    newRegion.center.latitude = location.coordinate.latitude - (0.2*newRegion.span.latitudeDelta);
    newRegion.center.longitude = location.coordinate.longitude;

    [self.mapView setRegion:newRegion animated:YES];

    self.mapView.showsBuildings = YES;
    self.mapView.showsPointsOfInterest = YES;
    self.mapView.showsUserLocation = YES;
}
```

Note: "LocationManager" class is a separate class of mine that just handles registering for location notifications from iOS and holding on to the most recently reported location. If you need help with that, it's a whole 'nuther question… :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is notification. Try to implement the below

```
//appdelegate.m
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
   if([[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationState]==UIApplicationStateActive)
   {
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"applicationEnterForeground" object:self];
   }
}

//yourViewController.m
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadMapView) name:@"applicationEnterForeground" object:nil];
}

-(void)reloadMapView
{
    NSLog(@"Reload your map view here");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

in your ViewController's `viewDidLoad` method add an observer to if user is loading the app again and write your code in the method to refresh map view

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(yourMethod)
                                             name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

in dealloc method remove observer

```
- (void) dealloc {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:Nil];
}
```